# kill PID in the bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, process, fuser

I am using in my bash script the following syntax to kill the PID of the script - AmbariAgent.py

```
kill $(  ps -ef | grep AmbariAgent.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2 }' )
```

from `ps -ef`

```
ps -ef | grep AmbariAgent.py | grep -v grep
root     63769     1  0 12:39 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/AmbariAgent.py start
```

I am just asking if there are more elegant approach instead of the cli -

```
kill $(  ps -ef | grep AmbariAgent.py | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2 }' )
```

?

we try

```
pkill AmbariAgent
```

but PID still up

```
# ps -ef | grep  AmbariAgent
root      3645     1  0 12:43 pts/0    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/AmbariAgent.py start
root     31018 61002  0 13:02 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto AmbariAgent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to kill the AmbariAgent process, then you can use a far shorter and more efficient command to kill it based on the name:

```
pkill -f AmbariAgent
```

Or whatever the name actually is:

```
pkill -f <name>
```

Added the `-f` switch so that it's matched against the entire line and not just the process name.

Comment: see my update in the question

Comment: pkill -f AmbariAgent
 this works

Comment: @yael I forgot about `-f` which is necessary since without it, it only matches the process name which is python and I'm sure that you don't want to kill all of the Python processes on the machine. `-f` kills it based on what matches in the line

Answer (score 0):

You can use below one line awk command to kill the process

Tested and worked fine

```
ps -eaf | awk '/AmbariAgent.py/ && $0 !~ /awk/{print "kill -9" " " $2}'|sh
```

Comment: `kill -9` isn't necessary or requested here